# WooCommerce: Checkout Page - order_review div overlaps the customer_details div

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce: Checkout Page

order_review div overlaps the customer_details div, so that you are unable to fill out your billing information. I've tried playing with the z-index but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a link to the product page: http://lifestylesconvention.com/shop/adult-couples-registration/

Please fill out the Form and then continue through to the Checkout page. There you will see what I mean. The div for order_review overlaps the div for customer_details on that particular page, so you are unable to fill out the information in the top section.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, lol. I'm sure the answer is staring me right in the face, but I just don't see it. Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: double: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93926/woocommerce-checkout-page-order-review-div-overlaps-the-customer-details-div

Comment: They people over there told me to post this question here. Should I not have done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce the problem in firefox.

I haven't found haven't found a solution yet.  But I'm confident the issue is jQuery/javascript.  Turn off javascript on the page and the problem goes away.  You have about 20 scripts loading on the checkout page and I'm afraid I haven't been able to isolate the one responsible.

Not sure what your skill level is, but a few things I would try:
  1. renaming the mecurial js directory (temporarily). About half of the scripts come from this directory. If you rename it, the browser wont be able to load them then you can isolate if any of them is causing the error.
  2. The problem seems to occur during an AJAX request for /checkout/pay/. My guess woocommerce is disabling the form while it AJAXs some data but then for some reason doesn't re-enable access.  Maybe because it can't find /checkout/pay/ (did you delete this page for some reason?)

Hope this helps...Sorry I couldn;t give a definitive solution - I've gotta to my own work.

Good Luck.

Comment: Wow! You are both correct! There's also an issue with the Javascript, and renaming the folder DOES fix the issue. Will go through the process of trying to figure out WHICH JS file is causing the problem. *sigh* Thanks for the advice! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimick the second WooCommerce column (perhaps delete that div from your checkout template as you don't use this for a shipping address?). The `float: right` clears the billing column. It looked differently in Chrome & Firefox btw, because in Chrome it would be 100% wide and float under the billing field, and in Firefox it sat to the right of that column (which I assume is what you want).

```
#order_review table.shop_table {
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Wow! You are both correct! There is definitely an issue with the CSS in Chrome. Thanks for the advice! Very much appreciated.